# Oracle 11g: SQLDeveloper |status: failure-test failed: IO error. connection reset|

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

**part 1** 
new / select database connection

info

```
 connection name: ziv 
 username:oracle
 password: xxxxxxx
 connection type: basic role: sysdba 
 host name : localhost.localdomain
 port: 1158
 sid: orcl
```

quest is to make new connection  what to do?

i trying to connect a database from sqldeveloper

but im get the follow error

error:

```
 status: failure-test failed: IO error. connection reset
```

**part 2**

**i change the port to 1521 and im get other error**

**status failure test failed IO error the nestwork adapter could not**
**establish the connection**

```
  [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl status
  LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-DEC-2015 09:16:27
  Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
  Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
  Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
  Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
  (HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
  TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
  Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

**part 3**

```
  [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl start
  LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-DEC-2015 09:39:16
  Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
  Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...
  TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  System parameter file is      
  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
  Log messages written to   
  /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
  Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost) 
  (PORT=1521)))
  Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  STATUS of the LISTENER
  ------------------------
  Alias                     LISTENER 
  Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -   
  Production
  Start Date                08-DEC-2015 09:39:18
  Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
  Trace Level               off
  Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
  SNMP                      OFF
  Listener Parameter File    
  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
  Listener Log File          
  /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
  Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  The listener supports no services
  The command completed successfully

  [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl status
  LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-DEC-2015 09:39:40
  Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
  Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  STATUS of the LISTENER
  ------------------------
  Alias                     LISTENER
  Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - 
  Production
  Start Date                08-DEC-2015 09:39:18
  Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 22 sec
  Trace Level               off
  Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
  SNMP                      OFF
  Listener Parameter File    
  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
  Listener Log File          
  /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
  Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  Services Summary...
  Service "orcl.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Service "orclXDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  The command completed successfully
```

**PART 4**

**okey so im try again and other error ^^ this time**

**status: failure- test failed : ora-01031 insufficient privileges**

**okey so now it work after the last step**

```
   **before**
   connection name: ziv 
   username: sys
   password: xxxxxxx
   connection type: basic
   role: sysdba 
   host name : localhost.localdomain
   port: 1521
   sid: orcl
```

**change the username from oracle to sys and it worked...**

```
  **after**
  connection name: ziv 
  username: oracle
  password: xxxxxxx
  connection type: basic
  role: sysdba 
  host name : localhost.localdomain
  port: 1521
  sid: orcl
```

**tnx for all for the help**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1158 is the default port for Enterprise Manager Database Console, not the database listener, and you can not log in there using SQL*Net or JDBC.

The default port for the database listener is 1521, try connecting using that port. You can check the listener port by:

`lsnrctl status`